# Strange behaviour of javascript variable with variablename "name"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I understand that javascript is dynamically-typed language so i can change the type of data assigned to a variable in javascript. Recently I started with javascript and found a strange behaviour when i was trying some commands in console window of google chrome browser. Please find the screen shot attached with the set of commands i ran through. In the 3rd command i am assigning number 10 to variable name which was created as string. But if i check the typeof name it still says string. I couldn't find a logical answer to this behaviour. But when i try the same sequence of instructions with other variable names it works as expected. Please can some explain this behaviour.

[screenshot of instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOZZK.png)

Answer (score 0):

All global variables in JavaScript in the Browser are properties of the `window` object.

`window.name` must always be a string, so that the global variable `name` will always be converted to a string.